# Inducing controlled CPU stress on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, cpu-usage

I am trying to induce controlled CPU Stress for some performance testing.

Currently inducing the Stress using below procedure.

```
  //Thread function to create 50% stress on one of the cores
unsigned __stdcall threadFunc(void *param)
{
    while(1)
    {
        //Start timer   
        //------ Operations-----
        //------ Operations-----
        //Get Elapsed time in ms
        Sleep(elapsedTime);     
    }
    _endthread();
}

MainFunc()
{
   //loop looking for input
if(inputDetectedToIncreaseStress)
   _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &threadFunc, NULL, 0, &threadId); //Creates a thread

}
```

With above code i expected to induce 50% CPU stress on a particular core.
For example in Quad core system, i expect the above code to induce 12.5% load but it is actually inducing 25% load, in my case wherein there are 8 cores it induces  12.5% load with the expected being 6.25% and it induces the same load without any sleep function too.

So to summarize i can get CPU load percentages 12.5,25,37.5,50,62.5,75,87.5,100 by creating threads without any sleep but not able to induce stress percentage like 95 even with sleep function introduced in an attempt to induce 50% CPU load on a particular core.

Could someone tell me where i am going wrong?

Operating System : Microsoft Windows Server 2012.
CPU-Cores : 8
Programming Language : C++
Timer Function : Uses Query performance Counter - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Not checking the value of 'elapsedTime' in your debugger is one problem.  Assuming the 'Operations' take a sane amount of time for this scheme, say 500ms upwards, then why not printf() out 'elapsedTime' or display it in a status bar pane or other visual component?

Comment: Also, not sure how you plan to pin this function to a core?  When it comes back from the Sleep(), it could pop up on any core.

Comment: I did check the value of elapsed time it was around 20 ms. Yes it can come up on any core but my issue is, i tried with just one thread but still i am not able to achieve the  50% usage on any core using sleep its always 100% on a particular core.

Comment: In other words, how do i stress a 8 core cpu by loads of 6.25% or less.

Comment: 20ms is likely getting rounded down to 0 since it''s of the order of the granularity of Sleep().  The thread is calling Sleep() and the kernel is just returning, so the thread uses a whole core.  Try 200ms tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try that and update.

Comment: Tried that but no luck, still having the same issue.